# Password fields present on an insecure

Tags: php, security, http, passwords

I got the following error message in my Firebug console.

> Password fields present on an insecure (http://) page. This is a
>   security risk that allows user login credentials ,to be stolen.

What is the reason for this error?
If this is regarding `http` and `https`, what do I have to do to convert `http://` to `https://`?

[image]

I am working on my local machine and I can not install SSL here. I can not log to the system due to this error.

I change the password field to text filed, but the same thing is happening.
Please help me to solve this without installing SSL to work on my local machine.

Comment: Yes, this has to do with `https` and `SSL`.

Comment: Why can't you install a `SSL` cert on your local machine?

Comment: This is just an info, it shouldn't prevent you from logging in.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is not error. It's not even a warning. It's a notice.

Secondly, this in no way affect your forms, POSTs and logging.

Lastly, nothing even requires SSL and HTTPS for user logins. Even many e-commerce websites don't use SSL, because they don't need to. All you need to know that if you create account on non-SSL page, is that password must be stron and unique (you shouldn't use the same password anywhere else).

**Note:**
SSL actually *is required* when you process critical users' data like credit cards' numbers. You can usually observe it on some e-commerce shops, which don't use SSL at all, but when you go to any of payment methods, you always end up with SSL.

Comment: No longer true in 2020 on firefox, and a warning in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

it's okay to have this error in development mode, but you should use https when you want to publish your website because login should be done through https because that prevent some hacker attacks like session hijacking.

Comment: *Note:* SHOULD is a little exaggeration. Currently `HTTP` is more and more secured and gap between `HTTP` and `HTTPS` is shrinking. Still, I'd use "It's recommended to use SSL if you storage users' personal data like credit cards numbers and stuff, but otherwise it's highly optional" instead of "You SHOULD use SSL when LOGGING"

Comment: hi Forien please read this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309199/must-logins-be-a-https-page

Comment: I prefer to refer to this post http://serverfault.com/a/177817 and selected answer on the same topic. And remember that SSL is always slowing server and cause it to use more memory and cpu.